# Laravel: Displaying logged in user for for non protected pages

Tags: authentication, laravel, view

I have a site with public as well as protected (ie. you must log in to access) pages.

How do I display the logged in user on the public pages?

References to Auth::user->name (etc) generate "Trying to get property of non-object" errors in views.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`Auth::user()->name`

Not

`Auth::user->name`

Comment: Actually that is what I;m using. So my post above was incorrect. So when I'm using Auth::user()->name I still get the error.

Comment: Hmm..  Have you tried passing the variable to the view rather than directly accessing Auth::user()->name from the view?

Comment: Same thing. I think this is actually impossible. I think laravel doesn't know the user at all unless the auth filter is in affect. There must be a way...

Comment: If `Auth::user()->name` returns 'Bob', and you send your view like so: `return View::make('myview')->with('name', Auth::user()->name);` you should be able to reference `name` from your view and it should show Bob.  Is that what you tried?

Comment: The problem is Auth::user()->name is null unless the request is for a protected route. I think people must put the name in the session.

Comment: If you're logged in it should work on all pages protected or not.

Comment: Noah. Thanks for your help. I can't explain it but my experience is different. For now, I'm using a session variable to show the logged in name.

Comment: Wish I could be of more help but you haven't given enough description and you take 4+ hours to respond.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is not logged in, you will get a "Trying to get property of non-object" error. You must first use Auth::check() to see if the user if logged in. For example:

```
@if(Auth::check())
    <p>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</p>
@endif
```